# Using windows 8 and a 32-bit USB stick

Tags: windows-vista

Can you use a USB stick, made on a 32-bit computer with vista,  when you buy a new 64-bit computer 
  with windows 8?
   Need to reformat the USB drive, how can I do that without destroying the files on it?

Comment: What exactly is a 32-bit USB stick?  Storage devices do not have a bitness.

Answer (score 5):

If it's just data on it you can use it fine. No need to reformat.
If it does anything fancy you may need to include that in your question.
Just files = no problem.